# How to iterate plot over different variables?

Tags: iteration, stata, stata-macros

I have the following code:

```
hist house1 if house1 >0 & house1 <200000, bin(25) fraction by(Year) 

graph export house1.png, replace
```

I would like to iterate it substituting `house1` with `car1` and `bed1` without copy-pasting the code and substituting, or at least something like:

```
var = "house1"

hist var if house1 >0 & house1 <200000, bin(25) fraction by(Year) 

graph export var.png, replace
```

So that I can change just the value assigned to `var`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [Stata tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/stata/info) for advice on how to ask Stata-related questions on here.

Comment: We can't tell how literally to take your example, but you're implying that the same limits apply to quite different variables. @PearlySpencer is taking your example directly without trying to guess what you really want, which is more than reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `foreach` loop will work:

```
foreach x in house1 car1 bed1 {
    display "hist `x' if `x' >0 & `x' <200000, bin(25) fraction by(Year)"
    display "graph export `x'.png, replace"
}

hist house1 if house1 >0 & house1 <200000, bin(25)fraction by(Year)
graph export house1.png, replace
hist car1 if car1 >0 & car1 <200000, bin(25)fraction by(Year)
graph export car1.png, replace
hist bed1 if bed1 >0 & bed1 <200000, bin(25)fraction by(Year)
graph export bed1.png, replace
```

Here `x` is a local macro that gets the values specified in `foreach`.

Note that the `display` command is used for illustration and is not necessary.